# rails 4: get all user post and user's friend post. Eager Loading Query not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

how to select all user post and user's friend post? I tried querying using the code below but it just gives me all post including user that are not friend.

```
Post.includes(:user, :user {friends: :posts}).where(is_private: false)
```

User Class

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, through: :friendships

end
```

Friendship class

```
class Friendship < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, class_name: 'User'
end
```

Post class

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :upost, presence: true

  belongs_to :user
end
```

can anyone explain to me why this query doesn't work?

```
Post.includes(:user, :user {friends: :posts}).where(user: {id: 1})
```

I would appreciate any pointers.

Comment: What happens when you change it to `Post.includes(user: [{friends: :posts}]).where(is_private: false).references(:users)`?

Comment: @Pavan I tried the code you posted and it also query a post of a non-friend user. any idea, to complete remove the non-friend user post?

Answer (score 0):

Includes does not do what you want to do. 
Your code fetches all the Public `(:private=>false)` Posts and then includes loads the `users` and their `friends` .
What you want to do can be accomplished by `where` and `joins`

Try this

```
Post.joins(:user, :user=>[:friends]).where(is_private: false)
```